# How can I change the sidebar width in the desktop and mobile view properly?

Tags: mkdocs, mkdocs-material

I'm currently setting up some documentation with `mkdocs` and `Material for Mkdocs` and want to increase the sidebar width.

I have included an extra `.css` file within the `mkdocs.yml`. And in the `.css` file I have changed the `md-sidebar` class to:

```
.md-sidebar {
  min-width: 320px;
}
```

This works fine for the desktop view. Unfortunately when I am reducing the browser window size and the page is switching to the mobile view, the whole layout is corrupt.

I know that setting a global width cannot be the right solution to satisfy both views ... but I have not found anything in the documentation of `mkdocs` or `material for mkdocs` to change stylesheets settings depending on the given viewport :(

Does anyone has an idea how to set the sidebar width depending on the current viewport?

Answer (score 0):

If you're still seeing the menu when collapsed on mobile and it won't expand properly, it's because you need to subtract the difference from the left like this;

```
.md-sidebar--primary {
    width: 15rem !important;
    left: -15rem !important;
}
```

This makes it work on both platforms for me.